# Prove that this operator is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces

Let $X,Y,Z$ be Banach spaces, and let $T:X\to Y$ be linear. Let $J:Y\to Z$ be linear, bounded and injective. If $JT:X\to Z$ is bounded, then T is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the closed graph theorem and show that $T$ is closed.